# Header of table has not border

Tags: tables

I have a two tables, and both of them has not vertical borders in their headers.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Quantification of opportunities of threat agent}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{Opportunities (Number of trial tries)} \\
    \hhline{-----}
     Level  & Zero &    One &  Finite & Infinite \\
    \hline
    Score   & 0    &    1   &  4      & 10 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{threat agent Opportunities}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

The below image shows the missed vertical border
[image]

Comment: Use `|c|` in your multicolumn statement, not just `c`

Comment: You are using the `booktabs` package but not actually using the `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` macros. You should switch to those as well as follow the advice in the `booktabs` documentation about not using vertical rules nor rules between every row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're loading the `booktabs` package, you might as well seize the opportunity to improve the "look" of the tabular material dramatically by (a) getting rid of all vertical lines and (b) actually using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package -- `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` in the case of the present table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}
% I've simplified the preamble to the bare minimum...
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Quantification of opportunities of threat agent}
  \label{threat agent Opportunities}
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{Opportunities } \\
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{(Number of trial tries)}\\
    \midrule
     Level  & Zero &    One &  Finite & Infinite \\
    Score   & 0    &    1   &  4      & 10 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just change `\multicolumn{5}{c}` to `\multicolumn{5}{|c|}`

Comment: Al-Motasem Aldaoudeyeh, sorry, but I didn't see any difference between your answer ans @Johannes_B comment. This question was actually solved by comment ...

Comment: @Zarko I think it's better for the site if answers are left as answers, rather than as comments.

Comment: even if it to pirate comment? At first, he should ask comment author if he is willing to make an answer or to say in answer, that the problem is solved by @Johannes_B comment and add some explanation or whatever as  his original contribution. By the way, similar questions was many, many times asked before, so more correct had be to find duplicate question, isn't it?

Comment: @Zarko Well I assume that an answer posted only seven minutes after a comment and using different wording has a chance of being arrived at independently, so I'd be reluctant to use words like "pirate". In any case we can be more welcoming to new users, and I think there's never a case to say that an actual answer should not have been posted because something was solved in the comments — comments are ephemeral and can go away, only answers are permanent.

Comment: @Zarko yes, this is a duplicate and I have marked it. Also I agree that pirating a comment to answer is not a good behaviour.

Comment: @Michael Fraiman. I did not pirate a comment to an answer. I simply saw the question and took a few minutes to open one of the documents, post the code in it, take a screenshot and then write the answer here in the forum. ShreevatsaR is right. It was just a delay issue.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh **(1)** Please remember, that this is *not* a forum, it is a Q-A community; **(2)** You are member for 9 days and have already posted 8 answers, which is a lot for a newbie. There is absolutely nothing personal, but please keep in mind that the majority of your answers weren't accepted well and a few of them duplicate comments of other people or even answers already given. If you are confused about usage of this site visit `meta` part, read the rules and investigate the answers of other people. Good luck!